# How to locate/redirect the path of controllers file in codeigniter using javascript?

Tags: php, javascript, codeigniter

How can I redirect a controllers file in codeigniter using `javascript`? In this case, I would like to open a file in a pop-up window.

This is my code:

```
<script>
window.open(
    '<?php echo $this->config->base_url()."contorllers/welcome_pop"?>',
    '', 
    'width=700, height=100, toolbar=0, menubar=0, location=0, 
     status=1, scrollbars=no, resizable=no, left=200, top=200');
</script>
```

The filename is:

```
controllers/welcome_pop.php
```

Thanks.

Comment: add please tag codeigniter

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try just to call the url?

```
<script>
window.open(
'/index.php/controller/<function>',
'', 
'width=700, height=100, toolbar=0, menubar=0, location=0, 
 status=1, scrollbars=no, resizable=no, left=200, top=200');
</script>
```

The  is the function which loads the welcome_pop view (probably index)